# Select plot linestyle with plotly pandas backend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I want to be able to select the linestyle with the pandas `plot` method with the `plotly` backend.

#### Matplotlib:

When I use the matplotlib backend in pandas, I can do:

```py
pd.options.plotting.backend = "matplotlib"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [4,3,1,2]})
df.plot(style={"a":"--", "b":"-"})
```

which allows me to select the linestyle for each column. The output is:

[image]

#### Plotly backend:

With plotly I can do

```py
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [4,3,1,2]})
df.plot()
```

[image]

How can I select the linestyle of a given line (or even a single line), with the plotly backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example just use:

```
fig = df.plot()
fig.data[0].line.dash = 'dash'
```

And you'll get:

[image]

Other options are:

```
['solid', 'dot', 'dash', 'longdash', 'dashdot', 'longdashdot']
```

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [4,3,1,2]})
fig = df.plot()
fig.data[0].line.dash = 'dash'
fig.show()
```

Comment: I found that solution, and I was currently writing that answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AdrienPacifico Thank you for accepting my answer! I was also exploring approaches with `df.plot.line()`, but this approach seemed to be the best for your use-case,